# JSON stringify on lists in C# web form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I use `JSON.stringify` for a textbox autocomplete for a web-form. What I want to do is; autocomplete a textbox for city names by getting appropriate city names from my database. Autocomplete works after 3 letters.

The problem is; suggested city names are shown in one line. For example, when I typed **are** to textbox *(which is named "MainContent_city")* it is shown like: ***"Arequipa,Arecibo,Are Ostersund,Arezzo,Arendal"*** in one line, as one string object. What I want is to show all of those city names line by line. Such as;

**Arequipa

Arecibo

Are Ostersund

Arezzo

Arendal**

Below is my javascript code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
   $("#MainContent_city").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
      var param = { cityname: $('#MainContent_city').val() };
      $.ajax({
      url: "HotelAdd.aspx/GetCities",
      data: JSON.stringify(param, null, param.length),
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
      success: function (data) {
   response($.map(data, function (item) {
     return {
         value: item
       }
     }))
    },
 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert(errorThrown);
   }
  });
 },
   minLength: 3
  });
 });
</script>
```

This is my C# code for "GetCities" method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCities(string cityname)
    {
        List<string> City = new List<string>();

        string query = "SELECT name FROM City WHERE name LIKE @SearchText + '%'";
        //Note: you can configure Connection string in web.config also.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", cityname);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds2);

        for(int i=0; i<ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            City.Add(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

        }

        return City;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is contained in `data.d`.

Change this `response($.map(data, function (item)` to `response($.map(data.d, function (item)`

```
success: function (data)
 {
   response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
   return 
    {
   value: item
    }
 }))
},
```